# MySQL Case with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I've a table (name=expense) like so:

```
id  amount  date
1   -1687   2014-01-02 00:00:00.0
2   11000   2014-01-02 00:00:00.0
3   1500    2014-01-03 00:00:00.0
4   -3800   2014-01-03 00:00:00.0
5   119500  2014-01-01 00:00:00.0
6   -2999   2014-01-04 00:00:00.0
7   5972    2014-01-04 00:00:00.0
..
8   7208    2014-12-31 00:00:00.0
```

I'm able to retrieve **income** and group it by month like so:

```
SELECT 
      SUM(amount), 
      date 
 FROM expense 
WHERE YEAR(now()) = YEAR(date) AND amount>0 
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

I'm able to retrieve **expense** and group it by month like so:

```
SELECT
      SUM(amount), 
      date 
 FROM expense 
WHERE YEAR(now()) = YEAR(date) AND amount<=0 
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

I want to know if there is a way to combine both these queries and retrieve both **income** and **expense** and group it by month in a *single query*.

Comment: Why is both MySQL and Oracle tagged? Do not tag products not involved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a Case statement:

```
SELECT
   sum(case when amount> 0 then amount end) as income, 
   sum(case when amount<=0 then amount end) as expense, 
   date 
FROM expense 
WHERE YEAR(now()) = YEAR(date) 
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

Comment: huh.. 2 case around sum!! I was fiddling with one case and it wasn't working, was lazy to post it here. But glad I did. Thank you @Florin Ghita